# How do I segment and filter out robot traffic in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, robots.txt, bots

Google Analytics automatically filters out some bot traffic (e.g. from Googlebot and Bing's bot), but some smart bots that execute JavaScript show up like normal users in GA reports. What's the best way to filter them out?

Comment: Which bots? It can help give you advice :)

Comment: Thanks for asking, Yahel. I was thinking of Yottaa and Gomez in particular. I wrote up a blog post answering this question here: http://blog.yottaa.com/2011/03/google-analytics-how-to-segment-and-filter-out-robot-traffic/

Answer (score 2):

I spent time researching this question and wrote up a detailed answer with step-by-step instructions and screenshots. I hope others find it helpful!

http://blog.yottaa.com/2011/03/google-analytics-how-to-segment-and-filter-out-robot-traffic/

Comment: This would be useful if this was generalised to exclude more bots, rather than just Yottaa. Perhaps you do this by filtering out by a broader regex to the user-agent? (e.g. includes "monitor", "bot", ... etc.) This seems like a massive fail on GAs part not to exclude this by default.